# How to set 4 edittexts side by side to each other in LinearLayout?

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

How to set 4 edittexts side by side to each other in LinearLayout, is it possible to do that? Please suggest me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185874/how-to-put-two-buttons-on-same-line-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_weightSum="4" >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

On `LinearLayout`, you should have:
-> orientation=horizontal
-> layout_weight=1
-> layout_height=0dp

On `EditText`, you should have:
-> layout_weight=0.25 (4*0.25 = 1)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```