# Two buttons of same width with several words in one line

Tags: android, button

I want to draw two `Button`s *in one line* with *equal width*. Say, they have captions: "Sample text" and "Extra text". They should occupy as low space as possible, but all words should be written.

Now it looks so: [image]

I wrote this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Sample text"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Extra text"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If I remove `android:maxLines="1"` and set `wrap_content` to width, `Button`s write a text, but fill different widths.

Comment: This could help you ;)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185874/how-to-put-two-buttons-on-same-line-in-android

Comment: is it mandatory to have same size for both button?

Comment: @Rumit, yes, that is why I ask for a help.

Comment: @CoolMind, then another option to have fix size for both buttons.

Comment: @Rumit, I agree with you. I think will calculate a size programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let you want to resize second button.

If a button contains an icon, center it with [How to center icon and text in a android button with width set to "fill parent"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634191/how-to-center-icon-and-text-in-a-android-button-with-width-set-to-fill-parent/). For instance, move a `Button` inside a `FrameLayout` or create a `LinearLayout` with `ImageView` and `TextView`.

If your case is custom view and a button is a `FrameLayout` with icon, override the following event:

```
boolean isButtonResized;

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

    if (!isButtonResized) {
        int buttonWidth = firstButton.getWidth();
        if (buttonWidth != 0) {
            isButtonResized = true;
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = secondButton.getLayoutParams();
            lp.width = buttonWidth;
            secondButton.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }
    }
}
```

If you have a button without an icon, only text, a resizing will be simplier:

```
secondButton.setWidth(firstButton.getWidth());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to locate two buttons on one line, you need to set `match_parent` to `layout_width` of `LinearLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Sample text"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Extra text"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry, this solution requires full width for a layout, while I want it to occupy as little place as possible, but both buttons are of the same width and in one line.

Comment: @CoolMind I see. why don't you set fixed width?

Comment: Thanks for your support. Possibly I will set widths programmatically (after measuring). I thought there was a solution, for instance, with custom views. The problem is that I can change a text after application start.

Answer (score 0):

Add layout weight to both buttons. So, it will assure you have the same dimensions for both.

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Also get screen size and set the size programmatically.

[Get Screen width and height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743116/get-screen-width-and-height)

Fixing particular button size will effect small size screens.

Comment: Congratulate you with your debut in SO! Possibly this can lead to a solution, but I hope there is an easy method.